# Swift. SpriteKit. Getting sprite to create randomly on X axis

Tags: random, sprite-kit, swift2

I've been trying to make the sprite spawn any where on the x axis, but when I use this code the sprite is spawned outside of the screen and not in a viewable area. If it helps I'm using an iPhone 6s.

```
let Enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "EnemyGalaga.png")//the pic name
    //setup random spawning
    let MinValue = self.size.width / 7
    let MaxValue = self.size.width  - 200
    let SpawnPoint = UInt32(MaxValue - MinValue)
    Enemy.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(SpawnPoint)), y: self.size.height)


    let action = SKAction.moveToY(-600, duration: (enemySpeed))//where to go and how long it takes
    Enemy.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))
```

Comment: From what I can tell, you want to spawn the enemies at the top of the screen, and have them move down?

Comment: yes that is what im doing

Answer (score 0):

When I run into problems like this I find it extraordinarily useful to insert print lines into the code so I can what the actual numbers are that I am generating.  Sometimes I think I am creating a number in a certain range when in fact I am not.  Also, sometimes, I am creating a number in the correct range but I didn't realize that the code was incorrectly assuming my device was in landscape mode, or vice versa.  Insert this line right after the line where you generate Enemy.position:

```
print(Enemy.position)
```